# Combine regex statements together

Tags: regex

I'm trying to combine these regular expressions into one. Anybody know if this is possible?

Basically I'm trying to check if a string has a lowercase letter, an uppercase letter and a number.

```
(.*[a-z]+.*)
(.*[A-Z]+.*)
(.*[0-9]+.*)
```

So these strings that would all pass

```
aA1
a1A
Aa1
A1a
1aA
1Aa
```

Examples that would return false

```
aa1
AA1
a1a
AAa
a1
1a
1AA
1A
etc..
```

Comment: And "a1" would fail? Also, are you checking password complexity? Don't do it.

Comment: @Schwern yes, it should return false... why not? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Password cracking has become very sophisticated and long gone are the days when having a number in your password meant quality. Either use a quality password checker, or don't bother. You'll just add complexity and annoy people who write good passwords. Ask on [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) for more detail.

Comment: @Schwern Thank you for the information! I'll look further into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach is to enumerate all six combinations:

```
[a-z][A-Z][0-9]|[a-z][0-9][A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z][0-9]|[A-Z][0-9][a-z]|[0-9][a-z][A-Z]|[0-9][A-Z][a-z]
```

Essentially, you've got characters of three types - **U**pper, **L**ower, and **D**igit. The six combinations are

```
LUD|LDU|ULD|UDL|DLU|DUL
```

As you can see, this gets complex pretty quickly. If you are dong it for password checking, doing character class counting in the host language is a better choice.

Comment: For certain complex values of "very simple". ;)

Comment: @Schwern I mean, this is about as straightforward as it gets: all you do is listing all six <s>hundred</s> options :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's nasty. (Examples are in Perl)

```
my $re = qr{(?:
    ([a-z]+) |
    ([A-Z]+) |
    ([0-9]+)
)+}x;
```

All of `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` must be defined (true won't cut it because 0 is false).

```
$string =~ $re;
print "Match" if defined $1 && defined $2 && defined $3;
```

You're better off for everyone's sake keeping it at three simple regexes and writing a subroutine.

```
sub is_valid_string {
    my $str = shift;

    return 0 unless $str =~ /[a-z]/;
    return 0 unless $str =~ /[A-Z]/;
    return 0 unless $str =~ /[0-9]/;

    return 1;
}
```